# Can two networks connected to a router both have a host with the same IP address but a different subnet mask?

Tags: ip, routing, wired-networking

I got stuck on this doubt about basic networking.
Here’s an extract from COMPTIA Official Network+ book:

*When two hosts attempt to communicate via IPv4, the protocol compares the source and destination address in each packet against the netmask. If the masked portions of the source and destination IP addresses match, then the destination interface is assumed to be on the same IP network.*

My doubt is, if PC1 sends an IP packet to either PC2 or PC3, how would it tell them apart if they have the same IP address?  According to what was said above, if PC1 wanted to send an IP packet to PC3, the packet would be received by PC2 as it’s on the same network ID.

[image: sameIPtwosubnets]

Comment: Is there any NAT configured?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a homework question

Comment: There's two types of routes: direct or indirect. Indirect is composed with a gateway (i.e. a router). If the indirect route is a host route (or a subnet route of `/24` or smaller) and/or has higher metric (or chosen to be used with method like policy routing), it is still possible for PC1 to reach PC3 without NAT. (Of course the same "tricks" will be necessary on PC3 for the replies to return).

Comment: With that said, normally people wouldn't do it that way as it at least violate the "semantics" of subnetting.

Comment: The question is a little confusing. On an IP network, you decide which host to address with an IP address and nothing else. You cannot address PC3 from PC1. The end.

Answer (score 2):

Except in very exceptional, non-standard and broken networks the configuration show in the diagram is not valid. (It could be valud if there were 2 routers and 1 switch, and the routers were doing NAT and the devices between the networks never communicated with each other.

The netmasks are almost irrelevant in the diagram above because despite the different netmasks everything would fit in the same /24.  The few cases where the netmasks would otherwise change routing decisions are nullified by the router.

In this case,  devices in the first network would not be able to see any devices in the second network and vice versa. In fact, the router serves no valid function.

** Ive ignored special cases where the router is deliberately doing non-routerish things like acting as a bridging firewall, and doing dodgy arp / ip manipulation stuff which is extremely non-standard and something most routers cant do.  Even then, it is impossible for 2 devices with (only) the same IP addresses to communicate with each other.

** PCs will not send packets to the router where they are destined for hosts in the same subnet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  If I understand you correctly, two subnets connected with a router should not have octets for the same network ID (not sure how to express this), or any host would not be able to send to the other subnet.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Correct. I would phrase it "the 2 IP ranges connected to the router should be in different non-overlapping subnets"

Comment: Super-thanks, perfect!  What would I do without you guys.

Answer (score 0):

No. Any IP address within your network is required to be unique, regardless of network mask/prefix length.

Since you can use addresses from RFC 1918 (192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 10.0.0.0/8) there's really no sense in trying to use duplicate addresses.